GITLAB CI - Listen to job status
Problem: Since GitLab CI doesn't provide a built-in method to handle cleanup tasks when a job is manually canceled, it's necessary to create a Python script that will take care of cleaning up processes when the job is either timed out or canceled manually. To achieve this, the script needs to continuously monitor the job's status.

os.waitpid ()
I cannot get pid to gitlab runner???
CI_JOB_STATUS but this seems after script usage


the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

Normally, you would use an after_script for cleanups, but unfortunately this is not supported for some cases such as cancelled jobs, though this functionality has been requested and planned for quite some time (see: #10158). Though, it appears very close to completion and set for release in GitLab 17.0 (next month's release). See the breaking change notice:

after_script keyword will run for cancelled jobs

Announced in GitLab 16.8 (Jan 2024)
Removal in GitLab 17.0 (May 2024) (breaking change)
To discuss this change or learn more, see the deprecation issue.

The after_script CI/CD keyword is used to run additional commands after the main script section of a job. This is often used for cleaning up environments or other resources that were used by the job. For many users, the fact that the after_script commands do not run if a job is cancelled was unexpected and undesired. In 17.0, the keyword will be updated to also run commands after job cancellation. Make sure that your CI/CD configuration that uses the after_script keyword is able to handle running for cancelled jobs as well.

In the meantime and more generally, you can 'listen' for job status changes by setting up a webhook for your project and listening for job events, which will include any job status changes, as well as runner information if needed. This may allow you to implement the cleanup you need in lieu of full support for this from GitLab.
